# Minimize $5\sqrt{36+x^2}+4(20-x)$ using Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am not familiar with Lagrange multipliers.
I am trying to minimize the following equation

$$\text{minimize}~ 5\sqrt{36+x^2}+4(20-x)$$
$$\text{subject to}~ 0 \leq x \leq 20$$

Can I use the Lagrange multipliers to solve this minimization problem?
Is the equation
$$5\sqrt{36+x^2}+4(20-x)-\lambda_1(x-20)+\lambda_2 x = 0$$ correct?
I know that the answer is x=8, but I am not finding this value. 
Can you tell me a good reference for beginners?

Comment: Check when to use Lagrange multipliers. You don't have constraints in this problem.

Comment: my constraint should be $0 \leq x \leq 20$. Is it not enough?

Comment: My fault, I should have clearly stated it as "equality constraints". Please read the wikipedia page for Lagrange multipliers. And then you'll see, you don't need that in this problem.

Comment: do you have also other reference?

Comment: There are extensions of the Lagrange multiplier method that deal with inequality constraints. These can be found in, for example, Simon & Blume's "Mathematics for Economists". In this case, it is probably better to just compute the unconstrained minima en compare them with the values of the function at $x=0$ and $x=20$.

Comment: Thanks, I solved like this